# AWS Health check URL failing after a couple minutes of setting it up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm creating a health check for an AWS instance. The URL is just a php file that returns: header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

Each time I add the health check, it seems to fail for a minute or two, then pas for a few minutes, then fail from there on out. But when I go to the URL in the browser it responds very quickly every time.

Any ideas why the health check would keep failing?

Comment: You should first check the web server access and error logs.  Do you see the tests arriving at consistent intervals from each of the various source addresses Route 53 happens to be using?  Is your server logging 200 OK responses consistently?

Comment: You can check the "Health checkers" tab of selected Healthcheck with detailed information for each checker.

Comment: I think the problem may be that I'm not using a load balancer. Should I be able to setup a health check to a particular instance?

Answer (score -1):

In order to access the EC2 instance from ELB, it must be defined in the EC2 security group to access the EC2 instance from ELB.

[Configure Security Groups for Your Load Balancer - Elastic Load Balancing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-security-groups.html)